# Mat_<uchar> for Image. Why?

Tags: opencv

I'm reading a code, in this code I can not understand why we use `Mat_<uchar>` for image (in opencv) for use:

- thereshold

what is the advantage of using this matrix?

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?#threshold) function accepts as *source* image a 1 channel (i.e. *grayscale*) matrix, either 8 bit or 32 bit floating point.

So, in your case, you're passing a single channel 8 bit matrix. Its OpenCV type is `CV_8UC1`.

A `Mat_<uchar>` is also typedef-ined as `Mat1b`, and the values of the pixels are in the range [0, 255], since the underlying type (`uchar` aka `unsigned char`) is 8 bit, with possible values from 0 to 2^8 - 1.

Comment: while Mat_<int> ?
Is not typedef-ined as Mat1b?

Comment: No, it's Mat1i, and contains integer values

Comment: So Can I use Mat_<int> for theresholding?

Comment: Well, do you know if exist the type Mat? if it exists, what are the differences between mat and mat_ <uchar>? thank you for all

Comment: Yes, [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) type exists, and is the [basic image container](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html). [Mat_](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id7) is just the templated version of a `Mat` and can be convenient when you konw the matrix type at compile type.

Comment: One more question... For thereshold Mat type is a good idea?
I don't undestand why in this code we use Mat_<uchar> and not Mat

Comment: Because doing so you are sure at compile time that the matrix is the correct type. Yes, it's a good idea (but I'd have used Mat1b, it's equivalent but shorter)

Comment: OK, but if i put in this code a simple Mat it don't work and the error is thereshold...
where thereshold(img,img,128,255,THRESH_BINARY)

Comment: I can't on this site. Can you contact me at storix@live.it  ? please

Comment: Post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here. It shouldn't be your top-secret code, but just a few lines that show the error you have.

Comment: yes for now it is little bit secret, Do you know if exists a message private on this site? thank you for all... i need help

Comment: nothing is secret on this site. This site provide answers to programming problems to help also other people. If you need private assistance you should probably hire someone. But since this seems a very basic problem, you should be able to create a short  snippet of 10 lines of code to show the problem. And doing that you'll probably get the answer yourself, usually.

Comment: However it give me error on

MatU img \\is the Mat_<uchar>
Point cur
int cur_val=img(cur)

Comment: No idea until I see some code... How am I supposed to know what are `img` and  `cur`, etc?